# Netbeans Debugging Java web application (without main)

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, web-applications

How can I use the Netbeans visual debugger in a Java Web Application ? I have no main method in my project.
Is it possible?

I'm doing the following steps:

1. Start Apache Tomcat in Debug Mode.
2. Right click on Project -> Debug
3. Web Application is correctly launched. But execution doesn't stop and wait on the selected breakpoints.

I created setenv.bat file in tomcat\bin folder with these commands:

- set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92
- set JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_92

CATALINA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"

JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"

In Attach Debugger I specified SocketAttach, dt_socket, Host=localhost, Port=8000

Comment: why would you have a main method in a web application? add breakpoints, and set your tomcat (or whatever server you use) to debug

Comment: When I click "Debug Project" in Netbeans it shows a <No main classes found> message. I use Tomcat server. How can I proceed?

Comment: don't click "Debug project", start your tomcat as debug, add your breakpoints and just run the application

Comment: Don't use "Debug project" but "Attach debugger", add the address of your tomcat an your good to go.

Comment: @andy_X91, in Netbeans right click on your project and select debug. this should start debug session for your project.

Comment: In Attach debugger I chose SocketAttach with dt_socket, localhost and 8000 as paramethers. But when I launch "Debug" the application doesn't wait in breakpoints. (i'm not sure if I have to add that setenv.bat file)